# Spring get current ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am using Spring MVC for my web application. My beans are written in "`spring-servlet.xml`" file

Now I have a class `MyClass` and i want to access this class using spring bean

In the `spring-servlet.xml` i have written following

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.lynas.MyClass" />
```

Now i need to access this using `ApplicationContext`

```
ApplicationContext context = ??
```

So that I can do

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) context.getBean("myClass");
```

How to do this??

Comment: @Autowired MyClass myClass should do the job!

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Simply inject it..

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

or implement this interface: [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

Comment: Maybe this can work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682858/spring-how-to-get-hold-of-application-context-in-webapp-and-standalone-program

Comment: The following `ApplicationContextProvider.java` answer looks to be the most reliable solution for this.

Comment: It's returning NULL everytime. To mention here that i am doing this inside a normal class that is neither a "@RestController" nor a "@Component"

Comment: According to Spring documentation, it's best to avoid @Autowired due to some issues. Here is the link https://spring.io/understanding/application-context. The best option is to go with implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface.

Comment: I am not sure how does this answers the question. You cannot auto wire the application context in the object not managed by Spring.

Answer (score 112):

I think this [link](http://www.java2novice.com/spring/application-context-object/) demonstrates the best way to get application context anywhere, even in the non-bean class. I find it very useful. Hope its the same for you. The below is the abstract code of it

**Create a new class ApplicationContextProvider.java**

```
package com.java2novice.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
            throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }
}
```

**Add an entry in application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider"
                        class="com.java2novice.spring.ApplicationContextProvider"/>
```

**In annotations case (instead of application-context.xml)**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{
...
}
```

**Get the context like this**

```
TestBean tb = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("testBean", TestBean.class);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I coded similar to Vivek. But I avoid creating new ApplicationContextProvider() everytime I need to call the getBean() from the context. What I did was to have **static** `ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()` method. Then, when it is time to need the current app context, I invoke: `ApplicationContextProvider appContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Yes Panini Luncher, that would still be good. As per your suggestion i will change it that way. :)

Comment: Add `@Component` on `ApplicationContextProvider` can avoid configuration in `aplication-context.xml`

Comment: Note: getter and setter of context should be synchronized. You will avoid a lot of headache specially for unit/integration-tests.
In my case similar ApplicationContextProvider held old context(from previous integration test) that caused a lot of tricky bugs.

Answer (score 54):

In case you need to access the context from within a **HttpServlet which itself is not instantiated by Spring** (and therefore neither @Autowire nor ApplicationContextAware will work)...

```
WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

or

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

---

As for some of the other replies, **think twice before you do this:**

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("..."); // are you sure?
```

...as this does not give you the current context, rather it creates another instance of it for you. Which means 1) significant chunk of memory and 2) beans are not shared among these two application contexts.

Comment: SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this) -  did the job for me in the Liferay portlet action filter's init() method.

Comment: Awesome, the processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext did all the job I needed. Many thanks @Jaroslav

Comment: ApplicationContextAware DOES work for me, when it is annotated with @Component as in Vivek's solution (I am initializing Spring context manually via extending AbstractContextLoaderInitializer / createRootApplicationContext)

Comment: Be warned... SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); doesn't happen immediately, so you can't use it as the first line in your constructor for example.

Comment: This works perfectly in a classical Java webapp (not spring-mvc managed).

Comment: Where should SpringBeanAutowiringSupport be called in my class? SledgeHammer says "not first line in constructor"... if not then where?

Answer (score 34):

If you're implementing a class that's not instantiated by Spring, like a JsonDeserializer you can use:

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
MyClass myBean = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: It doesn't work to me. My class is out of Spring context. I've tried to use your code but it give me a **null** as response. I'm talking about `ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your code

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext _applicationContext;

//Add below line in your calling method
MyClass class = (MyClass) _applicationContext.getBean("myClass");

// Or you can simply use this, put the below code in your controller data member declaration part.
@Autowired
private MyClass myClass;
```

This will simply inject myClass into your application

Answer (score 8):

based on Vivek's answer, but I think the following would be better:

```
@Component("applicationContextProvider")
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static class AplicationContextHolder{

        private static final InnerContextResource CONTEXT_PROV = new InnerContextResource();

        private AplicationContextHolder() {
            super();
        }
    }

    private static final class InnerContextResource {

        private ApplicationContext context;

        private InnerContextResource(){
            super();
        }

        private void setContext(ApplicationContext context){
            this.context = context;
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
        AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.setContext(ac);
    }
}
```

Writing from an instance method to a static field is a bad practice and dangerous if multiple instances are being manipulated.

Comment: There is `org.springframework.core.io.ContextResource` interface. I would suggest to choose different name for inner class `ContextResource` just to avoid mess.

Comment: @AlexanderRadchenko Ok, I changed it to InnerContextResource

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding @Autowire if your class is not a RestController or Configuration Class, the applicationContext object was coming as null. Tried Creating new class with below and it is working fine:

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware{

   private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws 
     BeansException {
    this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
   }
 }
```

you can then implement a getter method in the same class as per your need like getting the Implemented class reference by:

```
    applicationContext.getBean(String serviceName,Interface.Class)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** :Inject following code in class

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext _applicationContext;
```

**Step 2** : Write Getter & Setter

**Step 3**: define autowire="byType" in xml file in which bean is defined

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to inject applicationContext through servlet.

This is an example of how to inject dependencies when using Spring web services.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-soap-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:my-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

Alternate way is to add application Context in your web.xml  as shown below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/classes/my-another-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:my-second-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Basically you are trying to tell servlet that it should look for beans defined in these context files.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than having it with @Autowired is to let it be injected via constructor. Find some arguments pro constructor injection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737720/constructor-injection-vs-field-injection)

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public MyClass(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  //here will be your methods using the applicationcontext
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `main()` method has `SpringApplication.run()` method then you should remember ,it by default, returns the ApplicationContext object. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run(java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D)).
Meaning,you can do this:

```
ApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(YourMainMethodClassName.class,args);
MyClass obj=(MyClass)context.getBean(MyClass.class);
```