# How can i get beans from servlet context in filter

Tags: java, spring, servlets

This is my web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my Custom Filter like this.

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    //wac is root context, not dispatcherServlet's context   
}
```

I want to get dispatcherServlet's context(servlet-context.xml).

please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827548/spring-get-current-applicationcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i din't tested but you can try this
check in spring docs

```
DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet(request.getServletContext())
```